# Css not applying on div element

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with my css, I'm trying to make my X button appear to the top right corner of my the div frame. The problem is that it is just not appearing anywhere. the codes seems okay to me. I wonder what is causing this problem?. Can someone help? Please run the snippet you will see that the button x is not appearing at all!and I apologize for the unnecessary long html codes.

```css
.x {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    top: -10%;
    right: -10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="frame" onmouseover=""><button class="x">X</button><!--This button-->
    <div class="section">
        <h5>Only take into consideration of the  x button</h5>
        <center>
            <div class="uploader" onclick="selectFile(this)"></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" accept="image/*" onchange="handleImage(this)" /></center>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p style="color:white">A) '+A+'</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p style="color:white">B) '+C+'</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p style="color:white">C) '+B+'</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p style="color:white">D) '+D+'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container3">
            <div class="grid-item"><span style="color:green;font-weight:bold">Answer: '+answer+'</span></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"></div>
            <div class="grid-item"><input class="timer" type="range" min="3" max="20" value="10" oninput="showValue(this)">
                <h4>
                    <p>5 Minutes</p>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><br>
```

Comment: It's partially visible on the top right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zpLby9ca/1/ I just updated the code with positive values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are wrong. You're placing it on the top right corner and outside of the frame because of the negative values. Try this:

```
.x {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    top: 10%;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Itay Gal saves! xD

Answer (score 0):

**There is a problem with your positioning**

The absolute position makes it to the top right-hand corner, from right to left. By making it -10% you are taking it off the screen. You could position it with a positive number

**Without positioning**
[image: no positioning]